# Newly installed Windows Server 2003 R2 Missing Remote Tab In Properties Window

Tags: windows-server-2003, rdp, remote

**EDIT**

I figured out the problem.  Turns out that tab does not show up if you're not logged in as Administrator.  Thanks for the help regardless.

I just installed Windows Server 2003 R2 Standard x64 Edition Service Pack 2 on a virtual host.  I'm trying to enable RDP, but in the System Properties window there is no tab for Remote like there is with our other servers with the same OS.  Does anyone know why and how to fix it?

Comment: Great! Good for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. Turns out that tab does not show up if you're not logged in as Administrator. Thanks for the help regardless.

Answer (score 2):

In your Group Policy Object (GPO), go to <kbd>Computer Configuration</kbd> --> <kbd>Policies</kbd> ---> <kbd>Windows Components</kbd> --> <kbd>Remote Desktop Services</kbd> --> <kbd>Remote Desktop Session Host</kbd> --> <kbd>Connections</kbd> --> `Allow users to connect remotely using Remote Desktop Services` and set the option to `Enabled`.

This setting applies to Windows XP, Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows Server 2003, Windows Server 2003 R2, Windows Server 2008, and Windows Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 1):

Click <kbd>Start</kbd> --> <kbd>Run</kbd> and type this command:

> regsvr32 %systemroot%\system32\remotepg.dll

You can also try unregister this dll first, then re-register it once again.

> regsvr32 /u %systemroot%\system32\remotepg.dll

then

> regsvr32 %systemroot%\system32\remotepg.dll

Comment: That returns a dialog box titled: RegSvr32
And it has the message:  DllRegisterServer in C:\Windows\sysstem32\remotepg.dll failed.  Return code was 0x80040201

And and OK button.

Comment: Check if Remote Tab appeared. Did it return an error or succeed?

Comment: Sorry, read my edit.

Comment: Still no remote tab.

Comment: Extract a new copy of remotepg.dll from CD, put it into system32 folder and before that rename old one if exists. Then try to register the dll again. Seems like the required dll somehow became corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why your 'remote' tab is not there, but you can enable RDP using the command line:

```
reg.exe add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server" /v fDenyTSConnections /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

If you have the firewall running, make sure to allow RDP

Answer (score 0):

I went through all the different things to check online and it turned out that on multiple servers, the fDenyTSConnections was a REG_SZ and not a REG_DWORD.

I deleted the REG_SZ and made a new REG_DWORD with the 0 value, restarted, and the Remote tab was back.